# How can I get the xml file name inflated?

Tags: java, android, layout-inflater

If I am using the debugger in the line of `public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {` i.e. this method will be stepped into by the debugger, is there a way to find the xml file name that was inflated (I guess by the `MenuInflater`) to build the `Menu menu`?

Comment: You need to include some more of your code..

Comment: @ChristofferPass:Can’t I figure out the file somehow from the objects passed to the method?